# Access Query by form that runs SQL Server view as a backend query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a Access DB with SQL Server as Backend DB, all the tables in Access are linked from SQL Server. I want to create a query by form for keyword search. I am planning to have a access form such as:

Step 1: Shows a dropdown that lists all the tables in the DB, once a table is selected

Step 2: another dorpdown shows up that lists all the column names in the selected table, once a column is selected

Step 3: then a text box appears where I enter a keyword that will run a select query on the selected table with the criteria on the selected column that is entered in the text box and gives the result.

Now I have a SQL Server query to list the column names of a given table.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE (TABLE_NAME = 'table-name') 
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

I want to use this query for the second step.

I cannot understand how to connect Access QBF to run a query in SQL Server.
Should I make a view or stored procedure in SQL Server?

Can someone please tell me how to get this done.

Thank You.

Comment: I'm not sure, but i think in access you can only link tables o views from SQL Server. So to query Information_Schema, i would make a view for all the tables, and then link that view in access and filter with the desire table. Never the less, using access as backend for SQL Server is not a great option. And the filter option also provides few functional filters, because you can only filter for an specific value. I would make a little simple program for this.

Comment: @ericpap I have Access DB with a SQL Server as a backend not the other way around. Did you mean Access with SQL Server backend is not a great option, if so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy way to do this using MS Access.

If you set the row source of table select combo to:

```
 SELECT [name] FROM msysobjects WHERE type=4;
```

Then add a little code:

```
Private Sub cboTable_AfterUpdate()
    Me.cboFields.RowSource = Me.cboTable
End Sub
```

And set the field selection combo Row Source Type to Fields, you should get what you want.

You can link views from SQL Server to MS Access.